# In jquery What function Shall I want to use for move the menu from left to right and right to left

Tags: jquery, sidebar

Here is [link](http://vkacademy.in/test/) to my website. Click menu in left side bar.

In jquery, what function shall I use to move the sidemenu from left to right and right to left when I click the menu image icon. See the reference side http://www.wholefoodsmarket.com/.

Here is my js code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $('#menu_btn').click(function(e) {
            $('#sidemenu').slideToggle(1000);
        });
    });
    </script>`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
// to show menu
$('#sidemenu').animate({ left: 0% });

// to hide it
$('#sidemenu').animate({ left: -100% });
```

but place your menu button inside menu container to not cover it when menu pops out. Otherwise you wont be able to close the menu anymore.